# Is there a certain rule for dividing syllable in a word?

Tags: phonology

I am new in linguistics and I am an ESL student. When I check dictionaries such as Merriam-Webster, Random House Webster, Webster’s New world college, American Heritage, Cambridge dictionary etc and listen to the pronunciation, there are different division of syllable in a word. For example: Other /ʌ ðər/ /ʌð ər/ /ʌð ðər/ , cabin /kæ bɪn/ /kæb ɪn/ /kæb bɪn/. I have known the Maximal Onset Principle and Sonority Scale, but I am not sure about that. Is there a certain rule for dividing syllable in a word.

Comment: This might be a better fit over on [Linguistics SE](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: “There are no rules in English, only guidance. Some guidance looks like a rule; it probably isn't."

Comment: @Greybeard “There are no rules in English." 'This is not a string.' Mind you, I suppose 'There is only one rule in English [and this is it]' sounds odd.

Comment: Why would anybody but a phonologist be interested in dividing English syllables? They go by so fast and the variation is so vast that giving any rules is a waste of time.

Comment: @JohnLawler It seems to me that language is not all means and rules but that it is also art, and has among the qualities required to be reckoned with as such an indiscutable one, music. Why neglect that and not do the most of what your sense of aesthetics tells you could be done (within reasonable bounds)?

Comment: @JohnLawler They may go by fast but the ear is a fine organ and it can most of the time catch the subtle differences found even in fast speech, even if at times (often because of a lack of training) it can be fooled. It even catches them without our being conscious of it.

Answer (score 0):

There are rules, or rather, more than one set of rules.  There are different approaches to syllabification in English and the variety of English you study matters.

Here is what the *Longman Pronunciation Dictionary* says about syllabification. As far as British pronunciation goes, and more precisely its most evolved variant, RP,  this is the leading pronunciation dictionary.

*Note: all syllabifications are also those retained by LPD for GenAm.*

> Syllabic divisions are shown in LPD by spacing. This males the transcription of long words easier to read and makes certain details of pronunciation more explicit.
>
> The rhythm of a word or phrase is determined by the number and nature of the syllables it contains. Thus syllables 'carry' stress and intonation. (This is obviously important for poetry and singing.) This division of a word into syllables is called its **syllabification**.
>
> The question of syllabification in English is controversial: different phoneticians hold very different views about it. The syllabification principles adopted in LPD are those which most helpfully predict the **distribution of allophones** (see PHONEMES AND ALLOPHONES).
>
> LPD assumes that there is a syllable boundary wherever there is a boundary between the elements of a compound: thus **playtime** is 'pleɪ taɪm. It is also assumed that every word consists of whole syllables, and that consonants cannot belong to two syllables at once. Thus **city** must be either 'sɪt i or  'sɪ ti — the t cannot be in both syllables. (In fact it must be in the first, 'sɪt i, because the t is pronounced in a way typical of final t: not aspirated like initial plosives, but on the contrary potentially subject to T-VOICING and glottalling (see GLOTTAL STOP).)
>
> It is generally agreed that phonetic syllable division must as far as possible avoid creating consonant clusters which are not found at the edges of words. This is the **phonotactic** constraint. Thus **windy** might be 'wɪn di or 'wɪnd i, but it couldn't be 'wɪ ndi (because English words cannot begin with nd). LPD takes the view that the syllabification of this word actually parallels  its morphology: **wind+y**, 'wɪnd i. For the same reason, **language** must be 'læŋ gwɪdʒ, not 'læŋg wɪdʒ or 'læ ŋgwɪdʒ.
>
> The principle that LPD adopts is that **consonants are syllabified with whichever of the two adjacent vowels is more strongly stressed**. If they are both unstressed, it goes with the leftward one.
>
> In general this principle is subject to the phonotactic constraint. However, there are some cases where correct prediction of allophones requires us to override it.
>
> > (i) Certain unstressed syllables end in a strong short vowel, even though words cannot. In **nostalgia** the t is unaspirated (as in **stack** stæck, not as in **tack** tæck), so the syllabification  is (BrE) nɒ 'stældʒ ə.
> >
> > (ii) r can end a syllable, even though in BrE it cannot end a word pronounced in isolation. The r in **starry** 'stɑːr i is like the r in **star** is, and different from the more forceful r in **star runner**. Likewise, ʒ can end a syllable: **vision** 'vɪʒ n̩ [new, IPA syllabic n, former LPD syllabic n was ᵊn].
> >
> > (iii) Within a morpheme, tr and dr are not split. If petrol were 'pet rəl, as the phonotactic constraint leads us to expect (since English words do not end in tr), its t would likely be glottal and its r voiced (as in **rat-race** 'ræt reɪs). In fact, the tr in this word is pronounced as a voiceless affricate; so LPD syllabifies it 'petr əl.
>
> For further discussion, please see the author's article 'Syllabification and allophony' in Ramsaran, S (ed.), 1900, *Studies in the pronunciation of English*, London: Edward Arnold.

It is to be noted that LPD offers both the pronunciation of RP English and General American, and that the syllabification for this latter is the same as for RP (only the sounds may differ).

In my opinion, the energy with which words are pronounced in a given accent is a factor which goes hand in hand with the degree to which  the ideal type of phonetic syllabification is adhered to (this ideal type, again according to my opinion, being that in LPD). Pronunciations in which is felt more energy (clearly stressed words) make more readily for /'tju:t ər/ and /'kæb ɪn/ than  /'tju: tər/ and /'kæ bɪn/. I believe that syllabification of the second sort is much more likely in speech that shows a comparatively small degree of stress contrast; the principle referred to above ("consonants are syllabified with whichever of the two adjacent vowels is more strongly stressed.") seems to give justification to this point of view. The less salient stressing of American English could be one of the reasons why the RP syllabification scheme is, often enough, not that retained in  US models of GenAm.